# How to use "enum" values in select option in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, if-statement, eloquent, migration, laravel-blade

I have problem with build select in Laravel blade and use only two types values from database

I have column in my migraton:

```
$table->enum('contact_way', ['email', 'phone']);
```

I have to use it in my blade form to update, I use simple @if statement but it is not good

```
<select class="form-control" name="contact_way">
    @if ($customer_event->contact_way === "email")
        <option value="email" selected>Kontakt e-mail</option>
        <option value="phone" >Kontakt telefoniczny</option>
    @else
        <option value="email" >Kontakt e-mail</option>
        <option value="phone" selected>Kontakt telefoniczny</option>
    @endif
</select>
```

I want to use foreach staement where I use this to things and check witch one is correct and this show like selected but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to define your `<option>` twice. Give this a try:

```
<select class="form-control" name="contact_way">
    @foreach(["email" => "Kontakt e-mail", "phone" => "Kontakt telefoniczny"] AS $contactWay => $contactLabel)    
    <option value="{{ $contactWay }}" {{ old("contact_way", $customer_event->contact_way) == $contactWay ? "selected" : "" }}>{{ $contactLabel }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

This would generate your `select` with two options, each with a `$contactWay` for the `value=""` attribute and a `$contactLabel` for the actual HTML. Also, would default your selected value to whatever was input last, or the value from `$customer_event->contact_way`

Comment: Thanks it's works very good, I thought about it that I shouldn't defined my <option> twice. I will analyze your code and I will try use that way in the future.

Comment: The default selected value would be the first input, not the last one.

Comment: @ChinLeung No, the selected value is set via `old("contact_way", $customer_event->contact_way)`, or in this case whatever `$customer_event->contact_way` is set to. If it's `null`, or not set, then `email` would be set by default.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood the way you wrote the sentence. I thought you meant it would select the last element if nothing was selected previously.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. What I mean by "input last" is whatever you submitted to the Server last; that's what `old()` does.

Comment: @azbroja If this (or any of the other answers) help, please use the arrows to vote, and consider accepting one as the answer. Leaving a thank-you comment doesn't provide closure for the question (though they are appreciated none-the-less)

Answer (score 3):

There's many ways to do this, but look at your code.  You rewrite the entire options just to change one word: selected.

Just write a condition to handle that word (using ternary operators):

```
<option value="email" <?= $customer_event->contact_way === 'email' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Kontakt e-mail</option>
<option value="phone" <?= $customer_event->contact_way === 'phone' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Kontakt telefoniczny</option>
```

I don't see any need for a foreach loop with only two elements, but you could create an array of options to loop through if you really wanted.

Comment: Thanks for your help, its look very good in compare to my code.

Answer (score 3):

In your model:

```
protected $contact_way = ['email', 'phone'];
```

now loop as

```
@foreach($customer_event['contact_way']'as $contact)
        <option value="{{$contact}}" @if($contact == $customer_event->contact_way) "selected" @endif >{{ $contact}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: $customer_event['contact_way'] gives null